# Adding customer details to user in rest api

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I'm making a bookstore rest api using Spring Boot + hibernate and I'm not sure how should I proceed. So first of all User is created (using DTO not posted here):

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
  private Long id;


  @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "password_hash", nullable = false)
  private String passwordHash;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
  private Customer customer;

  @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Role role;

  // jpa requirement
  public User() {
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public String getPasswordHash() {
    return passwordHash;
  }

  public void setPasswordHash(String passwordHash) {
    this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
  }

  public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
  }

  public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
  }

  public Role getRole() {
    return role;
  }

  public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
  }
}
```

And then he can log in and search for books he is interested in. And when he wants to order them (using POST with JSON containing his books) he should enter his details as in my Customer entity (using DTO):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "customer_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
  private String firstName;
  @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
  private String lastName;
  @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false)
  private String phoneNumber;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
  private Address address;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;

  // jpa requirement
  public Customer() {
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
  }

  public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
  }

  public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public User getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
```

Is this a good approach? I don't know how else I could link user with customer -> customer has all the details to make an order while user is jsut registered guy, it works like that in may online shops but I;m not sure if I linked them correctly and my thought process is ok. COuld someone elaborate on that a bit?

EDIT: 
To clarify:

1. user registers and has only email and password - POST @ /users
2. user adds his customer details (without address) POST @ /users/1/customer : currently logged in user is found -> adding customer sets up customer_id in user table (OneToOne connection)
3. user adds his address details POST @ users/1/customer/address: currently logged in user is found -> customer is found through customer_id and then address is added and linked to the customer via address_id

All 3 using different DTOs - is this good approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can re-model your entities:

Customer is a user

Customer buys books

Create a User class with default properties.
Extend User class to create Customer class and add extra fields there.
Create a Book class.
Add an ArrayList of Book class as books to Customer class.

Once User is logged in you already have user details. Create a customer object for the user and add extra details when filled by User as a customer, add the selected books to the customer object and save the customer object to DB.